# share Fb,Tw and Email using Intent.action_SEND in android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, android-alertdialog, intentfilter

I have to post the text and email to FB,TW and Email.

Here i have created one imageview.if i have to clcik these imageview means the alert dislog box is opening.Here the following 3 item is listed: FB,TW,Email

Here if i have to FB on alert list which means it is go to FB app using action_send...also post the text and image.The other TW and Email app is hide.

If i ahve to click on TW on alert list means it is go to Tw app and post the text and image at the same time hide the FB,Email app...

How can i do ???

pls help me ..i have used below code...here i ahve to clicked Fb means nothing is happened ??? pls give me solution for these...my device installed FB,TW app also...then why nothing is happening ??? pls give me suggestion ??? what's wrong in my code ???

```
ImageView share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick (  final View v )
        {
            final CharSequence[] items =
            {
                    "Facebook", "Twitter", "Email"
            };

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SubCate.this);
            builder.setTitle("Share Via:");
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick ( DialogInterface dialog , int item )
                {
                    if (items[item] == "Facebook")
                    {

                        initShareIntent("facebook");

                    }
                    if(items[item] == "Twitter"){
                        initShareIntent("twitter");

                       } 
                    if (items[item] == "Email")
                    {

                        initShareIntent("gmail");

                    }
                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}



  private void initShareIntent(String type) {
        boolean found = false;
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");

        // gets the list of intents that can be loaded.
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(type) || 
                        info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(type) ) {
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  _Substring);
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,     _Substring);
                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(_Image)); 
                    share.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found)
                return;

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Select"));
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Here i have to run the app:

If i have to click Fb means facebook wall is opening...But the text is not displaying here...

If i ahev to click Tw means twitter wall is opening...Twitter text is displayed on wall..But image is couldnot loaded message is displayed ....

If i have to click email means gmail is opening and also displayed the text on subject well...

Why twiiter image couldn't loaded message is displaying...also FB text and image is not displaying ???? pls give me solution for these ????

Answer (score 0):

use SoicalAuth for this functionality  its very easy and you do not need create listview and layout for that....
see[this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/457153/How-to-integrate-Facebook-Twitter-Linkedin-in-Andr)

Comment: yes already i done these way..i wish to develop via action_send ly..thats y i have posted

Comment: ok. i have one suggestion ,if you have list to post on fb,twitter,etc then why u need button and there click event.your wish to develop this way that ok.

Answer (score 0):

In facebook its known issue that user cannot load the text via action send but you can upload the image. and also you can load the text using facebook api.

In twitter also you can send the image as well as text it wont show any problem.

Try with the below code. hope this will help you .

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

            shareIntent.setType("image/*");

            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);

            Uri uri = Uri.parse("file://"+combinedFilepath.trim());
                String extraString="set";
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,extraString);                                    
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, extraString);
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "app name");         

                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: i want to upload these image only:http://dev2.mercuryminds.com/website/var/tmp/thumb_6880_123_chitrangada-singh-john-abraham-and-prachi-desai_thumb_bolly__forfeed.jpeg....it is possible....

Comment: i am not getting any image. it says 404 file not found

Comment: action send will accept the images to upload from external memery only. it wont accept it from either internal memory or weburl. First you need to save it in sdcard and you can delete it. if you dont want further.

Comment: oh ok fine..fb wall is opening here.but the test is not display on facebook wall..whats wrong in my code

Comment: you mean text ? we cant send the text to facebook wall using action send

Comment: oh ok fine.i have used fb api...but how can i save and delete the dynamic weburl image in  sdcard for twitter image ???

Comment: first save the particular image in anyfolder.. before saving check for exists.. if it exists delete the image. then save it.. do it the same process every time..